# Find three consecutive entries of a row of Pascal triangle that are in the ratio of 1 : 2 : 3

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

> Find three consecutive entries of a row of Pascal triangle that are in the ratio of 1 : 2 : 3

This means that:

$$\begin{align}
2\binom{n}{k} =\binom{n}{k+1}\\ 
3\binom{n}{k} =\binom{n}{k+2}\\ 
\end{align}$$

I simplefied these equations:

$$\begin{align}
2\binom{n}{k} =\binom{n}{k+1}\\ 
\end{align}$$

Is the same as:

$$\begin{align}
2k+2 = n-k\\
3k+2 = n
\end{align}$$

And:

$$\begin{align}
3\binom{n}{k} =\binom{n}{k+2}\\ 
\end{align}$$

Is the same as:

$$\begin{align}
3(k+1)(k+2) = (n-k-1)(n-k)
\end{align}$$

I do not know how I could go further so that I would end up with the value of n and k. This is because I can not simplify 3(k+1)(k+2) = (n-k-1)(n-k) enough.

How can I proceed so that I can get the value of n and k for:

$$\begin{align}
3(k+1)(k+2) = (n-k-1)(n-k) \\
3k+2 = n
\end{align}$$

Comment: It's easier if you write it $3 \binom{n}{k+1} = 2\binom{n}{k+2}$. Then you get another linear relation between $n$ and $k$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $n=3k+2$, you can have
$$3(k+1)(k+2)=(\color{red}{3k+2}-k-1)(\color{red}{3k+2}-k)$$
Now solve this for $k$. (don't forget to check if each $k$ is sufficient.)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, coming from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1535614/find-n-and-k-if-binomn-k-1-2002-binomn-k-3003/1535639?noredirect=1#comment3127012_1535639), dividing the consecutive binomial coefficients yields
$$\frac21=\frac{\tbinom{n}{k+1}}{\tbinom nk}=\frac{n-k}{k+1}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
\frac32=\frac{\tbinom{n}{k+2}}{\tbinom{n}{k+1}}=\frac{n-k-1}{k+2},$$
and solving both for $n$ yields $n=3k+2$ and $n=\tfrac52k+4$, respectively, so $k=4$ and $n=14$.