# Are there four consecutive binomial coefficients in a row in an arithmetic progression?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Are there four consecutive
binomial coefficients in a row
in an arithmetic progression?

This is suggested by Will Jagy's comment 
to this question:

[Find $n$ and $k$ if $\:\binom{n\:}{k-1}=2002\:\:\:\binom{n\:}{k}=3003\:\:$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1535614/find-n-and-k-if-binomn-k-1-2002-binomn-k-3003)

Here is my answer:
No.
(If my algebra is correct
- $P(error) > 1/e$
)

(Nope - I had an error
pointed out by mathlove,
below.
Fortunately, the result is the same.)

To get 4 terms:

$\binom{n}{k}
=a$,
$\binom{n}{k+1}
=a+d$,
$\binom{n}{k+2}
=a+2d$,
$\binom{n}{k+3}
=a+3d$.

From the first 3,
$d
=\binom{n}{k+2}-\binom{n}{k+1}
=\binom{n}{k+1}-\binom{n}{k}
$

or
$\binom{n}{k+2}+\binom{n}{k}
=2\binom{n}{k+1}\\
$

or
$\frac{n!}{(k+2)!(n-k-2)!}+\frac{n!}{(k)!(n-k)!}
=2\frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}
$

or,
multiplying by
$\frac{(k+2)!(n-k)!}{n!}$,

$(n-k-1)(n-k)+(k+1)(k+2)
=2(k+2)(n-k)
$

or
$n^2-(2k+1)n+k(k+1)+k^2+3k+2
=2(kn+2n-k^2-2k)
$

or
$n^2-2kn-n+k^2+k+k^2+3k+2
=2kn+4n-2k^2-4k
$

or
$n^2-4kn+4k^2
=5n-8k-2
$

or
$(n-2k)^2
=5n-8k-2
$.

The last 3
give the same thing
but with
$k+1$ for $k$,
so that

$(n-2(k+1))^2
=5n-8(k+1)-2
$

or
$(n-2k)^2-4(n-2k)+4
=5n-8k-10
$
or
$(n-2k)^2
=9n-16k-14
$.

Equating,
$5n-8k-2
=9n-16k-14
$
or
$4n
=8k+12
$
or
$n
=2k+3
$.

To summarize,
if the terms are
$p, q, r, s
=a, a+d, a+2d, a+3d$
respectively,
I have used
$d
=q-p = r-q
=s-r
$
to get
$p+r=2q$
and
$q+s=2r$.

Another relation would be
$2a
=p+2q-r
$
and
$a
=q+r-s
$
or
$p+2q-r
=2(q+r-s)
$
or
$p-3r+2s
=0
$.

From this

$\begin{array}\\
0
&=p-3r+2s\\
&=\binom{n}{k}-3\binom{n}{k+2}+2\binom{n}{k+3}\\
&=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}-3\frac{n!}{(k+2)!(n-k-2)!}+2\frac{n!}{(k+3)!(n-k-3)!}\\
&=(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)-3(k+3)(n-k)(n-k-1)+2(n-k-2)(n-k-1)(n-k)\\
&\text{using Wolfy}\\
&=-4 k^3+12 k^2 n-12 k^2-9 k n^2+33 k n-2 k+2 n^3-15 n^2+13 n+6\\
&\text{again using Wolfy, substituting }n = 2k+3\\
&=-6 (k^2+5 k+6)\\
&=-6 (k+2)(k+3)\\
\end{array}
$

Since none of 
the roots of this
are a positive integer,
there are no $n$ and $k$
for which the
binomial coefficients
are in arithmetic progression.

Comment: I would not have expected four in a row in any case, as the graph of the binomial coefficients along a fixed row mimics a scaled version of the Gaussian normal distribution, basically $e^{- x^2 / 2}.$ The middle term of three must be pretty near one of the inflection points of the Gaussian, at $x= \pm 1$

Comment: Jack D'Aurizio
has a much simpler solution to the 3 in AP problem
here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018687/generalized-case-three-consecutive-binomial-coefficients-in-ap
He shows that there are an infinite number of 3 term APs with $n=a^2-2, r=(a+1)(a-2)/2$. This can be readily used to show that there no 4 in AP.

Comment: So, in row 7, we get $7,21,35$ with difference $14.$ Never noticed

Comment: Yep, and you can't write r+1 in that form also, so no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting 
$$(n-k-1)(n-k)+(k+1)(k+2)=2(k+2)(n-k)$$
note that
$$n^2+(-2k-1)n+k(k\color{red}{+}1)+\cdots$$

Then, $n=2k+3$ follows.

Now we have
$$\binom{2k+3}{k},\binom{2k+3}{k+1},\binom{2k+3}{k+2},\binom{2k+3}{k+3}$$

This cannot be an arithmetic progression because we have
$$\binom{2k+3}{k+1}-\binom{2k+3}{k}\gt 0$$
and
$$\binom{2k+3}{k+3}-\binom{2k+3}{k+2}\lt 0.$$

Comment: Thanks. I have (I hope) fixed it.

Comment: That's very nice. Much easier than mine.